# Download all extensions for datatables using bower

Tags: datatables

Is it possible to download all the extensions of datatables using bower like the fixheader,colReorder,Autofill etc..?

Answer (score 0):

[Datatables 1.10](https://www.datatables.net/) has got some new extensions and done away with a couple older ones. All the extensions are listed at [datatables github repository](https://github.com/DataTables?tab=repositories). Just go into any of the plugin repositories you want and you will find a bower.json file in it, and you can either copy the name and version of the extension to your own bower.json file like:

```js
"datatables": "~1.10.9",
      "datatables-responsive":"~1.0.7",
      "datatables-buttons":"~1.0.3",
      "datatables-colreorder":"~1.2.0",
      "datatables-fixedcolumns":"~3.1.0",
      "datatables-fixedheader":"3.0.0",
      "datatables-scroller":"~1.3.0",
      "datatables-select":"1.0.1",
```

and then run `bower update` or, while being in the same directory as your bower.json file, run : `bower install datatables-responsive` etc.